# View with join between field that can be null

Tags: mysql, join, view

I have 2 tables with more than 50,000 records each, each one of these.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `call_attempt` (
  `csvleads_id_fk` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `users_id_fk` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `call_id` varchar(50) default NULL,
  KEY `csvlead` (`csvleads_id_fk`),
  KEY `user_id` (`users_id_fk`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `recorded` (
  `record_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `agent_id_fk` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `lead_id_fk` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `duration` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `recording_url` text collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `recorded_at` timestamp NULL default NULL,
  `call_id` varchar(50) character set utf8 default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`record_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `filterme` (`recording_url`(100))
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=72158 ;
```

I added a call_id field to make the link. This means that new records must have these fields filled, at least in table **call_attempt**.

```
  call_attempt               recorded
-------------------       ----------------
users_id_fk call_id       call_id dutarion
-------------------       ----------------
1            NULL         NULL    10
2            NULL         NULL     8
3            NULL         NULL     5
4            NULL         ca12    19
50000        ca12         ca14     9
50001        ca13
50002        ca14
```

I need to throw me a view that all records in the table **call_attempt**, and if you find records in table **recorded** the duration is brought.

---

I tried LEFT JOIN but takes more than 50 seconds.

```
SELECT 
        `cal`.`csvleads_id_fk` AS `Id`,
        `rc`.`duration` AS `duration`
    FROM `call_attempt` AS cal       
        LEFT JOIN recorded AS rc ON (cal.call_id = rc.call_id AND (rc.call_id IS NOT NULL))
```

*84.625 sec / 0.000 sec*

---

Next, I tried doing a LEFT JOIN to a SELECT  table **recorded** with only the records that **call_id** are NOT NULL but don't let me create the view.

```
CREATE 
    ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED 
    DEFINER = `benscott`@`%` 
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
VIEW `callHistory4` AS
SELECT 
        `cal`.`csvleads_id_fk` AS `Id`,        
        `rc`.`duration` AS `duration`
    FROM `call_attempt` AS cal              
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT call_id , duration FROM `recorded` WHERE call_id IS NOT NULL) AS rc ON (rc.call_id = cal.call_id)
```

*Error Code: 1349. View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause*

---

Then I create another view with just the results NOT NULL from **call_id**.

```
CREATE 
    ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED 
    DEFINER = `benscott`@`%` 
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
VIEW `view_recorded` AS
SELECT call_id , duration FROM `recorded` WHERE call_id IS NOT NULL
```

And in the new view I join with view_recorded but also takes more than 40 seconds.

```
SELECT 
        `cal`.`csvleads_id_fk` AS `Id`,
        `rc`.`duration` AS `duration`
    FROM `call_attempt` AS cal       
        LEFT JOIN view_recorded AS rc ON (rc.call_id = cal.call_id)
```

*92.094 sec / 0.000 sec*

---

So, what options Do I have? Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this query:

```
SELECT `cal`.`csvleads_id_fk` AS `Id`, `rc`.`duration` AS `duration`
FROM `call_attempt_log` cal LEFT JOIN
     recorded_calls rc
     ON cal.call_id = rc.call_id AND rc.call_id IS NOT NULL;
```

The best index is `recorded_calls(call_id, duration)`.

Comment: Thanks @GordonLinoff